# jQuery toggle problem: animates twice

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a to me mystic problem with jQuery "toggle" method.
I click it once, but it animates twice. Go see for yourself!

[Demo](http://www.stultus.se/jobb/)

Page source is pasted below, (link will disappear when I have solved this).

**html:**

```
<ul class="topnav"> 
    <li><a>About us</a></li> 
    <li><a href="javascript:Void(0)" class="sublink">Store</a></li> 

        <li class="subnav"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Hours</a></li> 
        <li class="subnav"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Products</a></li> 

    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">@the Moment!</a></li> 
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li> 
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
a:hover{
    color: #CEDE43;
}
ul.topnav{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;                   
    font-size: 20px;          
}
ul.topnav li{            
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;                             
}
li.subnav{
    display: none;      
    font-family: 'Courier New', serif;    
}
```

**Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.sublink").click(function(){
            $(this).parents().find("li.subnav").toggle('slow');
        });        
    });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using such an old version of jQuery? You have version 1.2.3.

Comment: Nah. But I started this in wamp (localhost) and just copypasted some jquery file I had lying arond... ^^

Answer (score 1):

Target one specific parent instead of several with `.parents()`.

```
$("a.sublink").unbind().click(function(){
    $(this).parents("ul").find('.subnav').toggle(200);
});
```

I'm guessing it's an issue with that version where duplicate elements are added to the set when you do the `.find()` from multiple ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your finding is wrong, I put your code into jsfiddle, and it works fine.  is there something else on your page that may be interfering with this code?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZCVac/1/

Looking at your linked page I see what you're talking about.  Not sure what's causing it... investigating...

It looks like you're using a super old version of jQuery 1.2.3.  Try upgrading that.

Looks like using jQuery previous to 1.3 causes the problem.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this:

http://jsfiddle.net/treeface/tm5vQ/

Try updating your version of jQuery to 1.5 by including this link in your jQuery script tag:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js

When you do that, you should look into using the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method instead of calling `parents()` which returns all ancestors of an element.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.sublink").click(function(){
            $(this).parent("li").siblings(".subnav").toggle(200);
        });
    });
```

EDIT: Additionally you may want to do something like this otherwise you are going to run into problems if you want subnavs on more than one parent item:

```
    <script src="./Menu problem_files/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a.sublink").click(function(){
                $(this).siblings().find(".subnav").toggle(200);
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a>About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:Void(0)" class="sublink">Store</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="subnav" style="display: block; "><a href="javascript:void(0)">Hours</a></li>
                <li class="subnav" style="display: block; "><a href="javascript:void(0)">Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">@the Moment!</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Is this a more dynamic method than using closest() instead of parents()?

Comment: IMO you should use the method that achieves the results with the minimum amount of traversal - for something like a menu you have a fixed structure of elements so the more information you can give initially about where the elements exist in the DOM the more efficient the function is going to be. Closest() suggests you have no idea where the nearest one might be - but in the case of a menu you do know where, in relation to the parent element, the subnav elements are so why look any further than the obvious location.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine now. [See!](http://www.stultus.se/jobb/)
The first thing I did was update my jquery file. Stupid of me to not check that.
That change alone made it work fine. But i also updated my code to:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("a.sublink").click(function(){
              $(this).parent("li").siblings(".subnav").toggle(200); 
           });        
        });
```

But I seems like using closests() instead of parents() would have done the trick just as good.
Like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a.sublink").click(function(){
                $(this).closest("ul").find(".subnav").toggle(200); 
            });        
        });
```

Thanks for the fast answers!